# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException jsf composite component with primefaces dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException jsf composite component with primefaces dataTable

tabela-padrao.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

<!-- INTERFACE -->
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="uniqueId" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="var" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="selection" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="exportedFileName" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="renderedTable" default="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="primaryKey" required="true"/>
    <cc:clientBehavior name="customRowSelectEvent" targets="#{cc.attrs.uniqueId}" event="rowSelect" />
    <cc:clientBehavior name="customRowUnselectEvent" targets="#{cc.attrs.uniqueId}" event="rowUnselect" />
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>
    <p:dataTable value="#{cc.attrs.value}" 
                 id="#{cc.attrs.uniqueId}"
                 scrollable="true"
                 scrollWidth="100%"
                 var="#{cc.attrs.var}"
                 rendered="#{cc.attrs.renderedTable}"
                 selection="#{cc.attrs.selection}"
                 rowKey="#{cc.attrs.primaryKey}"                                             
                 selectionMode="single"
                 paginator="true"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="15,30,45"
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {Exporters}"
                 emptyMessage="#{bundle.tabela_nenhum_registro_encontrado}">
        <cc:insertChildren/>
        <f:facet name="{Exporters}">
            <h:commandLink style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px ;" title="Converter para Excel" >                                            
                <h:outputText  styleClass="fa fa-file-excel-o Fs20"/>
                <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="#{cc.attrs.uniqueId}" fileName="#{cc.attrs.exportedFileName}" />
            </h:commandLink>
            <h:commandLink style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px ;" title="Converter para PDF" >
                <h:outputText  styleClass="fa fa-file-pdf-o Fs20"/>
                <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="#{cc.attrs.uniqueId}" fileName="#{cc.attrs.exportedFileName}"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable> 
</cc:implementation>
```

Using the component

```
<h:form id="tabela-municipio">
<ezcomp:tabela-padrao value="#{municipioMB.listaMunicipios}"
                      uniqueId="id-tabela-municipio"
                      var="mun" 
                      primaryKey="#{mun.id}"
                      selection="#{municipioMB.municipio}"
                      exportedFileName="municipios">
    <p:ajax event="customRowSelectEvent" listener="#{municipioMB.onRowSelect}" update="@(form[id*='frm-municipio']),@(form[id*='tabela-municipio'])" />
    <p:ajax event="customRowUnselectEvent" listener="#{municipioMB.onRowUnselect}" update="@(form[id*='frm-municipio']),@(form[id*='tabela-municipio'])" />
    <p:column headerText="Pais" width="300" filterBy="#{mun.estado.pais.nome}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{mun.estado.pais.nome}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Estado" width="300" filterBy="#{mun.estado.sigla} - #{mun.estado.nome}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{mun.estado.sigla} - #{mun.estado.nome}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Município" filterBy="#{mun.nome}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{mun.nome}"/>
    </p:column>
</ezcomp:tabela-padrao>
</h:form>
```

I got this exception

> Advertência:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
> at javax.faces.component.UIData.setValueExpression(UIData.java:804)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentRule$ValueExpressionMetadata.applyMetadata(ComponentRule.java:107)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:81)
> at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:129)
> at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:102)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doNewComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:491)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:178)
> at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.ImplementationHandler.apply(ImplementationHandler.java:81)
> at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:326)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyCompositeComponent(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:387)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyNextHandler(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:188)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
> at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
> at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
> at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
> at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:206)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111)
> at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
> at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
> at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
> at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:174)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
> at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1006)
> at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
> at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
> at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
> at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
> at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
> at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Debug, debug, debug please, check where iti is throwing this, what the value is, what you expected there etc... just posting this is way to little effort from your side

Comment: I have put interruption point in every single method of the managed bean. The exception runs before even enter the managed bean. It doesnt get in any of the managed bean method. Do you have any hint i can folow to find the origin of that error ? 
"just posting this is way to little effort from your side" sorry about that. I´m kind of new in posting questions here.

Comment: You can also put breakpoints here: `javax.faces.component.UIData.setValueExpression(UIData.java:804) at...`  or just look at that source. That is what @VsevolodGolovanov most likely did.

Answer (score 2):

javax.faces.component.UIData:

```
public void setValueExpression(String name, ValueExpression binding) {

    if ("value".equals(name)) {
        this.model = null;
    } else if ("var".equals(name) || "rowIndex".equals(name)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    super.setValueExpression(name, binding);

}
```

var can't be a ValueExpression. I suggest just hardcoding some static var value right in the component. Component's user will just have to refer to this hardcoded value when defining columns. This would be a problem if you would want to nest your component though.